# Destacar linha selecionada da tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo uma tabela onde eu seleciono um Checkbox para habilitar um determinado input.
Gostaria de que quando eu selecionasse esse mesmo checkbox, a linha inteira da tabela ficasse destacada, mostrando que o usuário selecionou aquela linha.

```js
var cbs = document.getElementsByClassName('cb');

function cbClick() {
  var input = document.querySelector('input[data-id="' + this.getAttribute('data-id') + '"]:not([type="checkbox"])');
  input.disabled = !this.checked;
}

for (var i in cbs) {
  cbs[i].onclick = cbClick;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <th>CAMPO</th>
      <th>INFORMAÇÃO ATUAL</th>
      <th>INFORMAÇÃO CORRETA</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb" data-id="DtNascimento">
      </td>
      <td>Data de Nascimento</td>
      <td>11/11/1111</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" data-id="DtNascimento" disabled class="form-control datapicker" name="DtNascimento" id="DtNascimento">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb" data-id="DsEstadoCivil">
      </td>
      <td>Estado Civil</td>
      <td>Solteiro</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" data-id="DsEstadoCivil" disabled class="form-control" name="DsEstadoCivil">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb" data-id="DsOcorrencia">
      </td>
      <td>Grau de Instrução</td>
      <td>Segundo Grau Completo</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" data-id="DsOcorrencia" disabled class="form-control" name="DsOcorrencia">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma alternativa com Javascript puro:

<sub>Comentários no código</sub>

```js
var cbs = document.getElementsByClassName('cb');

function cbClick() {
  var input = document.querySelector('input[data-id="' + this.getAttribute('data-id') + '"]:not([type="checkbox"])');
  input.disabled = !this.checked;

    // parentNode.parentNode = td > tr subindo a hierarquia
    if(this.checked) {
        // muda a cor do fudo quando for marcado
        input.parentNode.parentNode.style.background = '#e1e1e1'; 
    } else {
        // remove a cor do fundo ao desmarcar
        input.parentNode.parentNode.style.background = '';
    }
}

for (var i in cbs) {
  cbs[i].onclick = cbClick;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <th>CAMPO</th>
      <th>INFORMAÇÃO ATUAL</th>
      <th>INFORMAÇÃO CORRETA</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="cb" data-id="DtNascimento" />
      </td>
      <td>Data de Nascimento</td>
      <td>11/11/1111</td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" data-id="DtNascimento" disabled class="form-control datapicker" name="DtNascimento" id="DtNascimento" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cb" data-id="DsEstadoCivil">
      </td>
      <td>Estado Civil</td>
      <td>Solteiro</td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" data-id="DsEstadoCivil" disabled class="form-control" name="DsEstadoCivil" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="cb" data-id="DsOcorrencia" />
      </td>
      <td>Grau de Instrução</td>
      <td>Segundo Grau Completo</td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" data-id="DsOcorrencia" disabled class="form-control" name="DsOcorrencia" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que precisava. Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi bem o motivo da sua mistura de jQuery com JS puro, mas de qualquer maneira acredito que isto resolva:

```
$(input).closest('tr').css('background', '#e1e1e1');
```

Comment: Aquela parte foi testes, não era para entrar no código, mas já alterei.
No seu caso, quando eu seleciono (checked) a linha fica selecionada corretamente, mas necessito que ao clicar novamente no checkbox, a linha volte ao normal. Só destacando quando o checkbox estiver selecionado.

Comment: Vou deixar minha resposta assim, já que a do AndréRibeiro já explicou isso, e ainda eliminou a necessidade de jQuery no seu código :)

Comment: Ok, Muito obrigado pela ajuda.